# How to use Perl's 'Digest::CRC' module to calculate DNP3 CRC

Tags: perl, crc

I'm trying to calculate a CRC for DNP3's link level.  The spec says it's a 2 octet CRC based on the polynomial X^16 + X^13 + X^12 + X^11 + X^10 + X^8 + X^6 + X^5 + X^2 + 1.  It's also inverted and put in the data block LSB first.

With Perl's Digest package, I set up the algorithm as:

```
my $ctx = Digest::CRC->new(width=>16, init=>0, xorout=>0xffff, refin=>1, refout=>1, poly=>0x3d65, cont=>0xea82);

$ctx->add(0x05);
$ctx->add(0x64);
$ctx->add(0x05);
$ctx->add(0xF2);
$ctx->add(0x01);
$ctx->add(0x00);
$ctx->add(0x00);
$ctx->add(0x00);

my $x=$ctx->digest;
printf("x=%04x\n",$x);
```

The example in the spec shown for the header:
05 64 05 F2 01 00 00 00 
the checksum should be
52 0C. I get x=91fc.

I've tried playing with all the parameters but can't seem to get it to come out.  Any suggestions?  Do I need to add() the data byte by byte? word (2 byte) by word?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add complete example input and expected output?

Comment: Are you sure about your poly value of `0x9EB3` ?  That converts to `1001111010110011` which does not match your polynomial.  Your polynomial would be `1001111010110101` which is `0x9EB5`.

Comment: Also, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks#Polynomial_representations - `All the well-known CRC generator polynomials of degree 
n
n have two common hexadecimal representations. In both cases, the coefficient of 
x
n
x^{n} is omitted and understood to be 1.` so you may need to try the variant without the leading coefficient.  ( I am not sure if this module uses that convention or not, its documentation could be improved... )

Comment: Your text and title mention [Digest](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest), but your code uses [Digest::CRC](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::CRC). Which is it?

Comment: Added complete routine and updated to use poly from Gammatester.  Still no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, with a little help from you folks, and hacking into the Digest::CRC and comparing, step-by-step the results given by the C Sample CRC calculations in the IEEE Std 1815, I came up with the following code:

```
my $ctx = Digest::CRC->new(width=>16, init=>0, xorout=>0xffff, refin=>1, refout=>1, poly=>0x3d65, cont=>0);

$ctx->add(chr(0x05));
$ctx->add(chr(0x64));
$ctx->add(chr(0x05));
$ctx->add(chr(0xF2));
$ctx->add(chr(0x01));
$ctx->add(chr(0x00));
$ctx->add(chr(0x00));
$ctx->add(chr(0x00));

my $x=$ctx->digest;
printf("x=%02X %02X\n",$x>>8, $x&0xFF);
```

The problem with my original code wasn't in the CRC digest, but the way I was passing the data into the module.  I passed it in as a single scalar value.  Digest::CRC would then append this to the data buffer with the code:

```
$self->{_data} .= join '', @_ if @_;
```

This (apparently) converted the scalar to a string (i.e. 0x05 to a "5").  Along comes the digest subroutine that access the first byte with the code:

```
ord(substr($message, $pos++, 1))
```

This resulted in digesting the value 0x35, not 0x05 as I had intended.

The solution was to pass the data into the module by wrapping the data as a string (i.e. chr(0x05)).

Thank you all, especially gammatester and dasgar, for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is compatible with **CRC-16/DNP** from http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm

```
width=16  
poly=0x3d65  
init=0x0000  
refin=true  
refout=true 
xorout=0xffff  
check=0xea82  
name="CRC-16/DNP"
```

You can verify this with https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html

Answer (score 1):

(This question is cross posted at PerlMonks - see [here](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1171326). The answer below is also cross posted at PerlMonks - see [here](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1171362))

I thought I'd challenge myself to see if I could figure this out. As I started looking into CRC algorithms, I quickly found myself in over my head. But I think that I was actually able to figure it out.

Looking at the source code of Digest::CRC, I took a guess that the value for 'const' should be 0 instead of '0xea82'. That got me closer for ASCII input. Combining that with the suggestion from the [Anonymous Monk](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1171335) got me closer for hex input. In both cases what I mean by getting closer is that I got the right characters, but in the wrong order. Basically, I needed to reverse the output by bits. For example, with your sample header, I was getting 'c52' instead of '520c'. The two bits here are '0c' and '52'. Reversing the two bits of 'c52' (or '0c52') produces '520c'.

In searching for references for CRC-DNP checksums, I found an online checksum calculator (found [here](https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html) - and is referenced in gammatester's answer). I used it to 'verify' the output of the following code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use Digest::CRC;

sub Left_Pad {
    my $value = shift;

    if (length($value) % 2) {$value = '0'.$value;}
    return $value;
}

sub Bitwise_Reverse {
    my $value = shift;

    $value = Left_Pad($value);
    my $offset = length($value);
    my $reversed;
    while ($offset > 0) {
        $offset -= 2;
        my $string = substr($value,$offset,2);
        $reversed .= $string;
    }
    return $reversed;
}

sub CRC_DNP_ASCII {
    my $value = shift;

    my $ctx = Digest::CRC->new(width=>16, init=>0x0, xorout=>0xffff, refin=>1,
                               refout=>1, poly=>0x3d65, cont=>0);
    $ctx->add($value);
    my $digest = $ctx->hexdigest;
    my $crc = Bitwise_Reverse($digest);
    return $crc;
}

sub CRC_DNP_HEX {
    my $value = shift;

    my $ctx = Digest::CRC->new(width=>16, init=>0x0, xorout=>0xffff, refin=>1,
                               refout=>1, poly=>0x3d65, cont=>0);
    my $offset = 0;
    while ($offset < length($value)) {
        my $string = substr($value,$offset,2);

        $ctx->add(chr(hex($string)));
        $offset += 2;
    }
    my $digest = $ctx->hexdigest;
    my $crc = Bitwise_Reverse($digest);
    return $crc;
}

my @data_list = ('056405F201000000','56405F201000000');
foreach my $data (@data_list) {
    say "Calculating CRC-DNP checksum for '$data':";
    my $ascii = CRC_DNP_ASCII($data);
    say "    ASCII input:  $ascii";
    my $hex = CRC_DNP_HEX($data);
    say "      Hex input:  $hex\n";
}
```

That produced the following output:

```
Calculating CRC-DNP checksum for '056405F201000000':
    ASCII input:  99fc
      Hex input:  520c

Calculating CRC-DNP checksum for '56405F201000000':
    ASCII input:  0751
      Hex input:  11e3
```

I've tried a few other examples to compare the output of my code versus the online calculator and I'm getting the same values for the CRC-DNP checksums.

Perhaps more knowledgeable folks might be able to identify issues with my code, but I think it should help you get further along with what you're trying to do.